# android - How to parse SMS textview

Tags: java, android, textview, sms

I'm trying a get SMS and parse textView.And my code,whats my mistake?

And ı test this code but not work
Where is my mistake this code,ı want get SMS and parse textview

```
public class ReadMsg extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;
ArrayList smsList;
TextView textsms;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_msg);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.idList);
textsms = findViewById(R.id.textsms);


    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);

    if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        showContacts();
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
}

private void showContacts() {
    Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    smsList = new ArrayList();
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();


    Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI,null,null,null,null);
    while (c.moveToNext()){
        String Number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        String Body= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
        smsList.add("Number: "+ Number + "\n" + "Body: "+ Body );
        textsms.setText(body);
    }
        c.close();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: SMS does not appear on textview

Comment: From first glance, it appears your line `textsms.setText(body);` is referencing the wrong variable.  I believe you want it to be `Body` (upper-case).  Set a breakpoint there and it should make more sense.